# Configuring module

Tags: excel, vba, module

I have a snippet (Credit: DanteAmor) which serves to countdown and close form. I have userform1 renamed as Question1. See code:‎

**The UserForm Code:**

```
‎Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()‎
Label1.Caption = "00:00:30" 'Write the starting number‎
Call CountDown‎
End Sub
‎

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
Call CountDown_End
End Sub
```

‎‎

**The Module Code**

```
Sub CountDown()
If Question1.Label1.Caption = "00:00:00" Then
Unload Question1
Exit Sub
End If
Question1.Label1.Caption = Format(TimeValue(Question1.Label1.Caption) - TimeValue("00:00:01"), "hh:mm:ss")
DoEvents
Application.OnTime (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")), "CountDown"
End Sub

Sub CountDown_End()
On Error Resume Next
Application.OnTime (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")), "CountDown", , False
End Sub
```

‎

My Challenge‎

I shall be creating Question 1 to 50. I have just created Question2 but the above module works for Question1 alone. I have done all I could to get the module work with Question2 and subsequent questions but can't seem to fix it. ‎Please can anyone help re-write the above module such that it works with all other Questions?

Thank you.

See Question1 form

[Question1 form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TbkER.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CountDown logic is hard-coded for Question1.  So the challenge is how to remedy this flaw.  My first thought was to pass the question as a parameter, unfortunately this does not work when using OnTime.  But essentially the same thing can be achieved by defining a UserForm variable in the module:

**UserForm**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
   Label1.Caption = "00:00:30"
   Set Question = Me
   Call CountDown
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
   Call CountDown_End
End Sub
```

**Module**

```
Option Explicit

Public Question As UserForm

Public Sub CountDown()
   If Question.Label1.Caption = "00:00:00" Then
      Unload Question
      Exit Sub
   End If

   Question.Label1.Caption = Format(TimeValue(Question.Label1.Caption) - TimeValue("00:00:01"), "hh:mm:ss")
   DoEvents
   Application.OnTime (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")), "CountDown"
End Sub

Public Sub CountDown_End()
   On Error Resume Next
   Application.OnTime (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")), "CountDown", , False
End Sub
```

Comment: Bravo Brian! The code works perfectly, serves my exact need. Thank you very much, you really have pulled a big load off my head!

Comment: If an answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark and upvoting by clicking the up arrow. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: The Check-mark worked but Up-voting arrow ain't working. Says, "Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score".